# Redirecting ports with Nginx on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to build a simple Docker project, where you have few containers that are joined by one Nginx server. Basically it's simpler simulation for my fullstack project. I have the problem with redirecting one containers main port to path in another project.

Project contains two modules and one `docker-compose.yml` file. Expected behavior is to see one html website on `http://localhost` and the other on `http://localhost/api` . When I run project, I see expected result on `http://localhost`, but to get to the other site I need to go to `http://localhost:4000`. How to fix it?

## Project files ([source code here](https://github.com/Ch3shireDev/DockerNginxReverseProxy))

### Module `Client`

index.html:

```html
this is website you should see under /api
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.2.0-alpine3.11 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
FROM nginx as runtime
COPY --from=build /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

### Module `Nginx`

`index.html`:

```
<p>this is index file. You should be able to go to <a href="/api">/api route</a></p>
```

`default.conf`:

```
upstream client {
    server client:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

### Main directory

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services: 
    client: 
        build: Client
        ports:
            - 4000:80
    nginx:
        build: Nginx
        ports: 
            - 80:80
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
            - client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 issues that I can find in your configuration:

1. You are redirecting to port 4000 on the client container, which you do not need to do, as the port 4000 is only relevant for your host machine. So the upstream config should look like the following:

```
upstream client {
    server client;
}
```

2. You are redirecting to /api on your client container, but your client container serves the content at /. You should change your default.conf to look like the following (mind the trailing slashes!):

```
upstream client {
    server client;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://client/;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, you can enter http://localhost/api/ to get to your client container. If you want http://localhost/api to work, you could redirect /api to /api/ in your default.conf.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are life saver and you definitely saved me next sleepless nights :D